# CombineLatest for multiple queries with Firestore

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore

it want to create multiple queries for Firestore to be able to combined observables to one. I use the snapshotChanges for Firestore (angularFire), then the combineLatest to group both. I have this error on TypeScript, and i am not able to get back both values on an Array, without using Payload :
Property 'payload' does not exist on type 'DocumentChangeAction[]'.ts(2339)

```
getAnnonces(limit){
    const requete1 = this.firestore.collection('annonce', ref => ref
    .where("secteurActivite","==", "Banque")
    .where("departement","==", "Rhône")
    .orderBy("date")
    .limit(limit)).snapshotChanges();

    const requete2 = this.firestore.collection('annonce', ref => ref
    .where("secteurActivite","==", "Finance")
    .where("departement","==", "Isère")
    .orderBy("date")
    .limit(limit)).snapshotChanges();

    const values = combineLatest(requete1, requete2)
    .subscribe(
      responseData => {
          this.tabTest = responseData.map(item => {
            return {
              id : item.payload.doc.id,
              titre :  item.payload.doc.get('titre'),
              secteurAct : item.payload.doc.get('secteurActivite'),
              departement : item.payload.doc.get('departement'),
              region : item.payload.doc.get('region'),
              description : item.payload.doc.get('description'),
              infosClefs : item.payload.doc.get('name'),
            };
          })
      });

    }//END GETANNONCES
```

Comment: I changed .snapshotChanges() with valueChanges() and now i can get back the values with concat, merge or combineLatest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 getAnnonces(limit){
    const requete1 = this.firestore.collection('annonce', ref => ref
    .where("secteurActivite","==", "Banque")
    .where("departement","==", "Rhône")
    .orderBy("date")
    .limit(limit)).valueChanges()

    const requete2 = this.firestore.collection('annonce', ref => ref
    .where("secteurActivite","==", "Finance")
    .where("departement","==", "Isère")
    .orderBy("date")
    .limit(limit)).valueChanges()

    merge(requete1, requete2).subscribe(console.log);

    }//END GETANNONCES
```

Comment: merge worked a treat for me. I had three queries to join and only got the one result I was after.